# Android WebView doesn't display website Menus on screen

Tags: android, android-layout, android-webview

I have a website that is up and running with 5 menu items.

I'm creating an Android App and trying to display the website on the app using WebView. The code is something like this

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        anWeb = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.App);
        WebSettings awSet = (WebSettings)anWeb.getSettings();
        awSet.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

        anWeb.loadUrl("https://mywebsite");
        anWeb.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
}
```

Everything works fine but the Menu of the site. Its doesn't fit into the screen and I need to move the screen toward left to see the menu.

My site is a responsive site.

I did everything including paying with alignment / match / wrap parent / margin.. Nothing works

Wondering if someone knows how to solve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Check these codes out

```
webview.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);//setting wide view
webview.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);//setting default zoomed out view
webview.setInitialScale(1);
webview.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);//setting zoom controls
```

Using these codes you can control the entire view of your webview

If you want to disable zooming and thereby not show the horizontal and vertical scroll bars then you can ignore the last code line and can also add this code

```
webView.getSettings().setSupportZoom(false);
```

Comment: Hi .. Looks to be working.. But there is a border at right as well as on top.. Is there anyway to remove it?

Comment: @DKG Are those borders the horizontal and vertical scroll bars?

Comment: yes.. Horizontal on Top and Vertical on right. The menu appears on them

Comment: @DKG have added some lines.Please check